# How to extract only a specific kind of link from a webpage with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract specific links on a page full of links. The links I need contain the word "apartment" in them.

But whatever I try, I get way more data extracted than only the links I need.

```
<a href="https://www.website.com/en/ad/apartment/abcd123" title target="IWEB_MAIN">
```

If anyone could help me out on this, it'd be much appreciated! 
Also, if you have a good source that could inform me better about this, it would be double appreciated!

Comment: first extract all the anchor tags and then filter using the keyword you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yon can use regular expression re.

```
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(Pagesource,'html.parser')
alltags=soup.find_all("a",attrs={"href" : re.compile("apartment")})
for item in alltags:
    print(item['href']) #grab href value
```

Or You can use css selector

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(Pagesource,'html.parser')
alltags=soup.select("a[href*='apartment']")
for item in alltags:
    print(item['href'])
```

You find the details in official documents [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

**Edited**:

You need to consider parent div first then find the anchor tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/apartment/for-sale/leuven/3000")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select("div[data-type='resultgallery-resultitem'] >a[href*='apartment']"):
       print(item['href'])
```

Comment: I've been going through so many things all day on their official documents but I'm too new to this to get it right because I'm still not able to do it. I'll try your method and see if that works! Thank you :)

Comment: @MoofinTheExplorer : Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've tried both ways but it's just returning me 'process finished with exit code 0'. I've been spending all day trying to use scrapy to get the job done but unsuccessful with that as well... maybe it's the websites html that's just too layered which is making it super difficult?

Comment: @MoofinTheExplorer : can you share the website url?

Comment: https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/apartment/for-sale/leuven/3000

I'm getting closer though, I've finally found how to extract some keywords which is a big step in the right direction for me, and soon I'll tackle the link issue with my newfound knowledge to see if I can get that going.

Comment: That works like a charm! For the past 2 days however, I've been trying to figure out how to return the building type (apartment, flat/studio, ...) the square meters and price in a list that I can add to excel. I've managed to get them in order but I don't know how to get them without the tags... 
for title in soup.findAll("div", class_="title-bar-left"):
    for price in soup.findAll("div", class_="xl-price rangePrice"):
        for sqm in soup.findAll("div", class_="xl-surface-ch"):
            info = title.append, price.append, sqm.append
            print(info)
    break